# How do I use a manipulator to format my hex output with padded left zeros

Tags: c++, manipulators

The little test program below prints out:

And SS Number IS =3039

I would like the number to print out with padded left zeros such that the total length is 8.  So:

And SS Number IS =00003039         (notice the extra zeros left padded)

And I would like to know how to do this using manipulators and a stringstream as shown below.  Thanks!

The test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    int i = 12345;
    std::stringstream lTransport;

    lTransport << "And SS Number IS =" << std::hex << i << '\n';

    std::cout << lTransport.str();

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you looked at the  library's setfill and setw manipulators?

```
#include <iomanip>
...
lTransport << "And SS Number IS =" << std::hex << std::setw(8) ;
lTransport << std::setfill('0') << i << '\n';
```

The output I get is:

```
And SS Number IS =00003039
```

Comment: If I am adding stuff before and after the formatted hex, how do the fill and width affect things? Is there a way for them to only apply to the formatted hex and not the whole stringstream?

Comment: I edited my answer to add the code.  I hope it will work for you.  Oh! Looks like "Let_Me_Be" beat me to it!

Comment: After setting the formatters and writing to the stringstreamm for the integer, you can readjust the setw() and setfill() as you like.  Alternatively, you could also pre-format a c-string using sprintf(char_buf, '%08X',i) and write that to the stringstream.

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
cout << std::hex << std::setw(sizeof(i)*2) << std::setfill('0') << i << std::endl;
```

Comment: Can't you just say `std::setw(8)`?  After all, that's what the OP says he wants.

Comment: @Kristo Oh, yeah, setw(8) would be fine, I overlooked that he wants always 8 characters. This will work with bit size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**setw**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) and [**setfill**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setfill/) functions as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    int i = 12345;
    std::stringstream lTransport;

    lTransport << "And SS Number IS =" << setfill ('0') << setw (8)<< std::hex << i << '\n';    
    std::cout << lTransport.str();  // prints And SS Number IS =00003039    
}
```